# Does Lazy Loading (React.Lazy) work in react native like its supposed to work in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lazy-loading

My team is working on a **React Native** project and some members recently implemented React.lazy() in the application with a purpose of making the **mobile** application more performant (Faster loading of the pages **after the application has been loaded**). As the aim purpose of Lazy Loading is to increase startup time only, do you think their approach is correct? Also I believe that as React.lazy() uses Webpack behind the scenes and as React Native does not support Webpack, Lazy Loading will not work. Can anyone please confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's in React-Native. You can use it for better performance.

You can use something like below:

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';


const Step1 = lazy(() => import(`./Step1`));


 <Step1
   title={'Test'}
   active={active}
   selectedItem={selectedItem}
   />
```

I hope it will help you to understand!